# SQLite3: exit indent

Tags: sql, sqlite

Really newbish SQL question here after searching StackOverflow.

Say you're working with the console in SQL (I use Sqlite3):

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO person (id, first_name, last_name, age)
    ...> VALUES (0, "Zed", "Shaw", 37);
    ...>
```

How do you exit from that innermost condition (from the ...>) back to the outermost level (sqlite>)? I've tried ctrl+c, .exit, exit, BREAK, .quit, .q, q, and everything else I can think of.

Comment: After the ";" and click "enter" the prompt should be automatically restore. Maybe you have some missed parenthesis or quote that should be closed first

Comment: i write it as a comment to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the `;` and click `enter` the prompt should be automatically restored.

If it's not happening, probably you have some missed parenthesis or quote that should be closed first.